# How to create PNR by CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ API Sabre

Tags: soap, sabre

I'm using CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ API to create PNR and book flight, flight infomation I had got by BFM API. But CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ api return error can not create pnr. Pls tell me, how can i create pnr for flight affter get BFM.

This is my request:

```
<CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/reservation/v2_1" version="2.1.0" haltOnAirPriceError="false" targetCity="KUL">
        <TravelItineraryAddInfo>
            <AgencyInfo>
                <Address>
                    <AddressLine>My Company</AddressLine>
                    <CityName>Dubai</CityName>
                    <CountryCode>PK</CountryCode>
                    <PostalCode>00000</PostalCode>
                    <StateCountyProv StateCode="DX"/>
                    <StreetNmbr>SZ Road</StreetNmbr>
                </Address>
                <Ticketing TicketType="7TAW"/>
            </AgencyInfo>
            <CustomerInfo>
                <ContactNumbers>
                    <ContactNumber LocationCode="LHE" NameNumber="1.1" Phone="971-589-697242" PhoneUseType="A"/>
                </ContactNumbers>
                <Email Address="darabjavaid@gmail.com" NameNumber="1.1"/>
                <PersonName NameNumber="1.1" PassengerType="ADT" >
                    <GivenName>ADULT</GivenName>
                    <Surname>KHAN</Surname>
                </PersonName>
                <PersonName NameNumber="2.1" PassengerType="CNN"  >
                    <GivenName>CHILD</GivenName>
                    <Surname>KHAN</Surname>
                </PersonName>
                <PersonName NameNumber="3.1" Infant="true" PassengerType="INF" >
                    <GivenName>INFANT</GivenName>
                    <Surname>KHAN</Surname>
                </PersonName>
            </CustomerInfo>
        </TravelItineraryAddInfo>
        <AirBook>

            <OriginDestinationInformation>
                <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2019-02-15T21:30:00" FlightNumber="804" NumberInParty="1" ResBookDesigCode="V"  Status="NN">
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="SIN" />
                    <MarketingAirline Code="OD" FlightNumber="804"/>
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="KUL"/>
                </FlightSegment>
            </OriginDestinationInformation>
        </AirBook>
        <AirPrice>
            <PriceRequestInformation>
                <OptionalQualifiers>
                    <PricingQualifiers>
                        <PassengerType Code="ADT" Quantity="1"/>
                        <PassengerType Code="CNN" Quantity="1"/>
                        <PassengerType Code="INF" Quantity="1"/>
                    </PricingQualifiers>
                </OptionalQualifiers>
            </PriceRequestInformation>
        </AirPrice>
        <PostProcessing RedisplayReservation="true" >
            <EndTransaction>
                <Source ReceivedFrom=" TESTING"/>
            </EndTransaction>
        </PostProcessing>
    </CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ>
```

This is my response:

```
<CreatePassengerNameRecordRS xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/reservation/v2_1">
       <Error type="Application" timeStamp="2019-02-14T21:24:31.556-06:00">
            <SystemSpecificResults>
                <Message code="ERR.SP.BUSINESS_ERROR">PNR has not been created successfully, see remaining messages for details</Message>
                <Message code="ERR.SP.BUSINESS_ERROR">Could not find the PNR locator in the End Transaction response</Message>
            </SystemSpecificResults>
        </Error>
    </CreatePassengerNameRecordRS>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try again without "targetCity="KUL""? This is changing the PCC to KUL, and I don't think you would want to leave your actual PCC. "KUL" would be a pseudo city code used by airlines and not travel agency Sabre users.

Comment: yeah , i tried again without targetCity, but API return same response, and has some warring: 
<Message code="ERR.SP.BUSINESS_ERROR">PNR has not been created successfully, see remaining messages for details</Message>,
                    <SystemSpecificResults>
                        <Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">OTA_AirPriceLLSRQ: UNABLE 00 AVAILABLE</Message>
                        <Message code="0293">UNABLE 00 AVAILABLE</Message>
                    </SystemSpecificResults>
I don't know what that mean ?

Comment: That means flights are not available in those classes. If it's the exact information received from BFM, it's likely that the availability for those flights in those classes has gone to 0 since the time BFM ran the search.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the orchestrated option with EnhanchedAirbookRQ + PassengerDetailsRQ as it is way more stable.